# Error when retrieving data from AWS Price List Service API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm studying AWS and trying to retrieve data from AWS API. This time, AWS Price List Service. So I read the official document and followed it by using java sdk executed it. The error starts from  GetProductsResult result = awsPricing.getProducts(request); How can I fix ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Filter filter = new Filter();
    filter.setType("TERM_MATCH");
    filter.setField("ServiceCode");
    filter.setValue("AmazonEC2");

    Filter filter2 = new Filter();
    filter2.setType("TERM_MATCH");
    filter2.setField("volumeType");
    filter2.setValue("Provisioned IOPS");

    Filter[] filters = {filter, filter2};
    //AWSPricing awsPricing = AWSPricingClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_2).build();
    AWSPricing awsPricing = AWSPricingClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_2).build();

    GetProductsRequest request = new GetProductsRequest().withFilters(filters).withFormatVersion("aws_v1");

    GetProductsResult result = awsPricing.getProducts(request);



}

Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: api.pricing.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1064)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
at com.amazonaws.services.pricing.AWSPricingClient.doInvoke(AWSPricingClient.java:389)
at com.amazonaws.services.pricing.AWSPricingClient.invoke(AWSPricingClient.java:365)
at com.amazonaws.services.pricing.AWSPricingClient.executeGetProducts(AWSPricingClient.java:329)
at com.amazonaws.services.pricing.AWSPricingClient.getProducts(AWSPricingClient.java:304)
at com.amazonaws.samples.Test2.main(Test2.java:31)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: api.pricing.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:27)
at com.amazonaws.http.DelegatingDnsResolver.resolve(DelegatingDnsResolver.java:38)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy8.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1236)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-pelong.html) says you need to point at **AP_EAST_1** or **US_EAST_1**